# Management data collector upload to MDW on remote server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am trying to setup data collection and upload to an MDW on a remote server. During the setup wizard i can connect with the sa account but the upload job seems to insist on using windows authentication and the account doesn't have permission on the remote server.

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939169%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) states that i need to "make sure that the SQL Server Agent account will have access to the MDW database if it has been configured on a remote server. To ensure this access, you can create a SQL Server Agent proxy account and add it to the dc_proxy database role for the msdb database."

However do i need to do this on the server where the data is collected or on the server to which the data is uploaded? Also it seems i have to use a credential to setup the proxy. What credential do i need to use?

Thanks very much for all advice and tips.

Answer (score 0):

I got that to work by giving the machine itself, permissions to those databases.  [domain][machinename]$.  I added the account and gave it db_reader permissions to the [source] and db_writer to the MDW database.
Of course, it is always a much better practice to set up a domain account for the SQL Agent to run under, but some companies make that hard to accomplish.